# Запятая перед как

Tags: запятая

Как величайшая реликвия хранится в каждой семье память о той страшной войне- в пожелтевших фотографиях, похоронках, письмах с фронта. Нужна ли запятая после реликвия, есть ли здесь значение причины? Я думаю, что да. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как величайшая реликвия хранится в каждой семье память о той страшной войне- в пожелтевших фотографиях, похоронках, письмах с фронта. - на оборот падает логическое ударение, здесь он
 выступает в роли обстоятельства образа действия: хранится как? как реликвия, можно заменить творительным падежом: хранится величайшей реликвией. Или наречием: хранится бережно.

Так же, как, например: Тропинка извивалась как змея(ПО-ЗМЕИНОМУ),(ЗМЕЕЙ).

Причины здесь не вижу. Нельзя сказать,что память хранится, потому что она реликвия.

Answer (score 2):

Странная чёрточка тоже не нужна: "хранится память в фотографиях".

Comment: Тире возможно как обособление пояснения (где хранится) в виде однородных членов в конце предложения.

Answer (score 1):

> Нужна ли запятая после реликвия?

Не нужна.